# Is there any way to use a chrome session inside an application?

Tags: android, google-chrome, session

I want to create an Android application that takes feed from a website and notifies about it every time it updates.

The problem is that the notification is personal and it requires an active user session.

I thought about login normally using Google Chrome,

and using this session to get the right feed (site.com/notifications.php)

As I said I can't simply send a request to this page because a user have to be logged in. (otherwise the server will return a page of "please login" message)

Again - can I use a Google Chrome in an application, to download a good page?

Tried to Google it - nothing relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What about making the user log in to the website in your app using a WebView? If you do this, you can get the session-cookie by fetching it inside the WebView.OnPageFinished()-method. Whenever you do a request to this page later, you can then send your cookie with the request, and you should not get the "please log in"-reply - but rather the actual content.

As far as accessing sessions from within chrome in other applications; I'm fairly certain this is not possible due to security reasons. If this were possible, any app could access any session - which would be very dangerous. Imagine a malicious app using your PayPal session that's stored in chrome.

I reccomend using tools such as Fiddler, and log in to the service while Fiddler logs the activity. This way you can see what the session-cookie looks like, and you'll have a better understanding of what's needed when you create a request to get the desireable response. Fiddler also comes with a HTTP request composer, where you can easily test HTTP-requests, to make sure they work, before you implement them in your code.

Hope this helps.